# How to implement IInputStream UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, inputstream

I should get an IInputStream to pass to the method: CreateFromStreamAsync, I have to specifically use this method because I use an AudioGraph (the uri that I pass to the method is a uri to listen to the radio)

"HLS" I guessed it from the following [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.streaming.adaptive.adaptivemediasource.createfromstreamasync?view=winrt-22000)

Code class StreamRadio:

```
 public class StreamRadio : IInputStream
 {
    public IAsyncOperationWithProgress<IBuffer, uint> ReadAsync(IBuffer buffer, uint count, InputStreamOptions options)
    {
        return AsyncInfo.Run<IBuffer, uint>(async (token, progress) =>
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            var output = buffer.AsStream();
            var outputRadio = output.AsInputStream();
            IBuffer bufferRadio = new DataReader(outputRadio).ReadBuffer(64);
            return bufferRadio;
        });
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
 }
```

Code Method:

```
StreamRadio streamRadio = new StreamRadio();

var adaptiveMediaSourceResult = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromStreamAsync(streamRadio, new Uri(uriRadio), "HLS");
if (adaptiveMediaSourceResult.Status != AdaptiveMediaSourceCreationStatus.Success)
{
     return null;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: IRandomAccessStream  is inherit from inputstream, you could use `IRandomAccessStream` as inputstream, and   IRandomAccessStream can be get from file [OpenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.openasync?view=winrt-22000#Windows_Storage_StorageFile_OpenAsync_Windows_Storage_FileAccessMode_). And what you want to read inputstream from？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
 var random = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri(uriRadio));
 IRandomAccessStream stream = await random.OpenReadAsync();
 var adaptiveMediaSourceResult = await AdaptiveMediaSource.CreateFromStreamAsync(stream, new Uri(uriRadio), "HLS");
```

Comment: If I click it says that I can mark tomorrow